# Android Dynamic single row layout

Tags: android, json, android-layout

I am trying to create a dynamic layout. My layout is being provided from JSON. What I need to do place a button and an edit text field in a single row. The edit text field should always fill the screen real state and the button should be only its text width size. The button could get placed before or after the edit text field.

[image: Goal]

Code wise I am trying below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonDataValue.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(jsonDataValue.get(i));

                if (jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("editBox")) {
                    EditText editText = new EditText(context);
                    editText.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
                    editText.setWidth(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    editText.setHeight(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    System.out.println("width: " + LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                    System.out.println("hight: " + editText.getHeight());
                    linearLayout.addView(editText);
                    System.out.println(linearLayout.getOrientation());
                }
                else if(jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("button")) {
                    Button button = new Button(context);
                    button.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
//                  button.setWidth(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    linearLayout.addView(button);
                }
            }
```

I am getting the below:
[image: getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following update as below:

```
             if (jsonDataViewType.get(i).toString().equals("editBox")) {
                    EditText editText = new EditText(context);
                    editText.setText(jsonDataValue.get(i));
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            editText.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
```

Comment: Hey tried this. But it doesn't work. I am not able to update/edit my question. So I'm not sure how to post a screen shot.

Comment: Can you reply? or share your screen for me

Comment: I think use just swap LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT and LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT because the constructor define is LinearLayout.LayoutParams(int width, int height). I also update from my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. This seems to be it so far.

Comment: I am trying to add another button to the already added two. But it comes on the same row. http://imgur.com/TbRVN5X How can I move the test button below.

Comment: LinearLayout only arrange child view in horizontal or vertical => To resolve your problem, you need to have a parent LinearLayout that set as vertical. Each row will be added to one child LinearLayout that set as horizontal, child LinearLayout will add to parent LinearLayout

Comment: Hey thank you for your help. Below is what I got so far, but its not working:
<LinearLayout oid.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutVertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: You don't use properly. The child LinearLayout only add 2 items that you want, for other button or text, you need create new child LinearLayout

Comment: Could you show please? So far, I am understanding is:
LinearLayout
     LinearLayout  -> btn, edit text
     LinearLayout  -> btn
?

Comment: Got this so far, how would I center that Test button horizontally. 
http://imgur.com/NbrqJWj